# React native assembleRelease unable to fetch data with axios

Tags: android, ios, react-native, axios

I have a live working restful API returning JSON data created with nodeJS and uploaded to a webServer. Also I'm using react native to build the front end for both android and IOS. The api works fine and returns data as expected when I build debug version of the app in android using 'react-native run-android'. But the app seems to be unable to fetch data from the API while I build the release version in android using 'cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease'. I can't see any hits in the node server from my app.
I'm using axios for my http requests.

Comment: Could this be related that you're trying to fetch data from _http_ instead of _https_? If so, check this solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23986#issuecomment-475783025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is resolved. As of Google's official documentation, requests to a web Server is possible only with a secured domain with valid SSL certificate.To force HTTP requests from insecure domain or domain with self signed certificate, just add a file in

> "yourProject/android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml"

with following contents-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">

        <!-- For React Native Hot-reloading system -->
        <!-- If you are running on a device insert your computer IP -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your own domain ip</domain>

        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>

    </domain-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />

</network-security-config>
```

and then import the xml file by adding this line to AndroidManifest.xml between application tag-

```
<application...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
...>
```

Comment: Hi! It didn't work for me, any other sugestions? Thank u!

Comment: hi.. even i am stuck. didn't work for me. tried almost everything.  any suggestion please. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in *android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml* works well for me. We may want to add also in the *debug* folder (sibling of *main*) for development purpose.